# JBoss Errai, should I replace all my GWT-RPC client calls with it?

Tags: jboss, push, comet, gwt-rpc, errai

Is there still any benefit to using GWT-RPC to do my client-side calls if I have JBoss Errai (which I downloaded in order to do server push)? Or would I lose nothing if I just used Errai calls for everything, client and server side? Can it send all the same data types, and does it perform as well, as GWT-RPC for client-originated calls?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Errai can substitute the GWT-RPC mechanism, the difference is the boilerplate code that you won't write; and you can inject dependencies through CDI in both client-server sides.